Proof seems wrong but I don't know why.
T.P.- Let O be the set of all odd integers. Prove that O has the same cardinality as $2Z$, the set of all even integers.
Proof:
$Let f:O\rightarrow2Z,f(x)=2x, \forall x \in O$
Proof that f is 1-1:
Suppose $f(x1)=f(x2)$, for any integers $x1,x2 \in O$.

$\therefore 2x1=2x2$
$\implies x1=x2$

Proof that f is onto:
Let $y\in2Z$. By definiton of $2Z$, $y=4k+2$ for any integer k. Let $m=2k+1$, and $m\in O$ by definiton of O. It follows that

$f(2k+1)=4k+2=y.$

Hence f is onto.
Searching up similar proofs online none of them are like this. I'm confused about the onto part mainly. Should i change it or is it correct?


Let $y\in2Z$. By definiton of $2Z$, $y=4k+2$ for any integer k.

This is not correct. What is the definition of $2\mathbb Z$?
Even better, what are the first few positive members of $2\mathbb Z$,
and what do they say about your formula $y=4k+2$?

Your function cannot be onto because its output is always twice an odd number. For example, $2\mathbb{Z}$ includes $4 = 2 \times 2$, which is twice an even number, making it impossible for your function to cover all elements of $2\mathbb{Z}$. Instead, consider using the function $f(x) = x + 1$.

But 2k+1 is always odd, and 4k+2=2 times 2k+1.

@Vince Again, your function cannot be onto because there are elements in $2\mathbb{Z}$ that cannot be obtained from any element of your set $O$ via $f$. For instance, $4$ is an example. There is no odd number $x$ such that $f(x) = 2x = 4$.

that makes sense.

Here you have used wrong definition of $2\mathbb{Z}.$
Any element $y \in 2\mathbb{Z}$  means $y=2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}.$
But you have taken $y=4k+2$ that means $y \in 4\mathbb{Z}+2$
also, $4\mathbb{Z}+2$ $\subset$ $2\mathbb{Z}.$
As $4 \in 2\mathbb{Z}$ but $4 \notin 4\mathbb{Z}+2$
That means onto is proved if the co-domain is $4\mathbb{Z}+2$ instead of $2\mathbb{Z}$.

my mistake was assuming any positive integer can be represented as 4k+2.
